# Why django forms instead of html forms?

Tags: html, django, forms

Hello I am new to Django. I am finding it hard to understand how Django forms work. My question is why to use Django form when we can use HTML forms?

Answer (score 0):

its all about re-usability. I want to raise one more question from you for the sake of understanding that

"why use django framework instead of html, css and Javascript code and back-end with core php"

We don't have to code manually for HTML form and implement different type of validations because Django provides already.

If you have reached Django documentation [djangoproject.com](https://www.djangoproject.com/). It says that you don't have to reinvent the wheel just understand and use builtin functionality. Once you are able to understand all the components and modules you are ready to go large scale application development with strict deadlines.

So, it is a good way to spend more time to understand the builtin functionality and use it instead of re-inventing the wheel.

Hope you find it helpful

Answer (score 0):

Django's forms framework handles many tasks :

- the  HTML display : Auto-generate a HTML form from a form widget
- the  validation : Validate submitted data against a set of rules
- data cleanup  : Convert submitted data into Python compatible types
- form redisplay-with-errors : Redisplay the HTML form  with errors if there's any.

Answer (score -1):

**According to GOOGLE....**

> Django forms are a way of generating forms on the page, and managing
>   them. ... The primary purpose of Django forms is to validate data. You
>   can use them with data not submitted through an HTML POST. Rendering
>   them, as HTML is something else that they do, but it isn't their main
>   purpose.

Comment: dear @Sikander there is no need to copy and paste things because it can do all. Our main purpose is to clarify things.